# rosserial_arduino error on terminal

Tags: arduino, rosserial, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I write this command on terminal:
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB0
but I change my port from USB0 to ACM0 as I work on ACM0

it appears to me that:
[INFO] [WallTime: 1374151755.600608] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1374151755.601022] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1374151755.603582] Error opening serial: could not open port /dev/ttyACM0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/ttyACM0'

and I rum roscore in a new terminal

I am on groovy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67648/rosserial_arduino-error-on-terminal/) by [ahmed.shamroukh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5253/ahmed.shamroukh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your serial port doesn't exist. Are you sure your arduino is plugged in?

`ls /dev/ttyACM*` and `ls /dev/ttyUSB*` may help you find it.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahmed.shamroukh](https://answers.ros.org/users/5253/ahmed.shamroukh/) on 2013-07-19**:
I did what you told me but I have a new error:
[INFO] [WallTime: 1374246906.900536] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1374246906.901156] Connecting to /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
[INFO] [WallTime: 1374246909.946657] Failed Packet Flags
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1374246924.016878] Lost sync with d